# How can I light an object for a turntable animation?

Tags: light, lighting, loop

I need to make a turntable animation for an object, but I am not sure how to light it to get a consistent light all around? What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

1. One method is to add multiple spotlights surrounding the scene: 
   [image]
2. Since World light comes from all directions, Another method is to change the world color and increase the World light strength:

[image]

[image]

You can also experiment with different types of lights and angles to get the results you are looking for.

Here is the Wolrd lighting + 4 point lights plus a 3d mesh put in the middle:
[image]
Each light is 150w and the world lighting is pure white with a strength of 0.4.

Comment: Hi there! thanks for the response. Will definitely try this out. But it appears that Suzanne seems a little washed out? Would it be better to do a normal 3 point light set-up (or what not) and then parent it to the empty?

Comment: Hi, I updated it by putting the World lighting + 4 point lights at the bottom of the original post.